# No Internet Access for Metro Apps

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, ipv6, modern-ui

I have a Laptop running Windows8 that is connected to the Internet via LAN. Because I do not have a WiFi router at the moment, I am sharing Internet over a hostednetwork (ICS enabled for the LAN adapter). This works great and no issues whatsoever.

Recently, I installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK, that installed some additional virtual adapters for Hyper-V. Now, Windows reports that I am not getting Internet via my physical LAN adapter but a Adapter called "vEthernet". My phisical Adapter is still enabled but IPv4/IPv6 shows "Not connected" (although I see packets comming and going). I had to enable ICS for the new vEthernet Adapter and the hostednetwork works again.

My issue is that none of the Metro apps (exception for Metro IE) have Internet Access. It's even more weird because the apps get push notifications (notifications and tile show new information) but inside the app, no Internet.

When I first installed the Windows Phone SDK, a Network Bridge was installed (showed always "unplugged") but now it is gone. As far as I understood, you cannot have a Network Bridge with one of the adapters enabling ICS anyway.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : kftzf544
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : upc.de

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-0C-6A-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2975:fde4:1e6c:e0dd%33(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.80.80(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1174410589
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-1F-CD-84-4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter Virtual Switch) #1:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85c6:8f29:a161:1b04%26(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.27.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 877399918
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-1F-CD-84-4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30) Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : upc.de
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-EB-69-81-3F-BD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b08d:433f:2adf:e790%23(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 88.153.34.69(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, May 26, 2013 10:53:50 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, May 26, 2013 12:46:27 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 88.153.32.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.154.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 476113769
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-1F-CD-84-4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 80.69.100.214
                                       80.69.100.110
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4b1:90a8:e3c8:4d9%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 558632814
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-1F-CD-84-4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4E-0F-6E-2E-DE-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-0F-6E-2E-DE-12
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.upc.de:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : upc.de
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : upc.de
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:5899:2245::5899:2245(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
                                       2002:c058:6301::1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 80.69.100.214
                                       80.69.100.110
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{81CF595E-D4C4-4135-B232-B8661053D8F7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B9A3A5FA-5CBE-4C6E-9B62-AB3FEE65E742}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{39EB3E2A-D748-49EA-A2F9-49909916DE4C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: @techie007 They seem similar but the set-up is very differnet (I am using Internet via LAN and require a hostednetwork). I have network connectivity in Desktop apps but not in Metro apps. Disabling all Hyper-V adapters is not a solution because I can't user Internet in the Windows Phone Emulator.

Comment: What is that 6to4 setup doing in there?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also created by the Windows Phone SDK set-up ... I don't know D;